# Help, I am having difficulty understanding p-groups! Kindest regarts

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, prime-numbers, p-groups

So, I need to memorise this proof for an exam, and it seems to be just checking the subgroup criterion. However, I don't actually understand what p-groups are by the definition at the top! Some illustrative examples would be much appreciated!

[image: Pgroups]

In particular, this confuses me.

[image: pgroups 2]

Comment: I think, memorizing proofs is not the right way. First you should try to make examples for yourself. Did you already ggogle $p$-group? There are many examples on the web.

Comment: See, I can understand that those all have prime powers, but I have edited the question to show the bit that I really can't understand.

Comment: What is exactly causing the confusion?? $\pi$ number or $n_{\pi}$. Can you specify?

Comment: So, I don't really understand how $30_{\pi}=6$.

Comment: the largest number which divides 30 and is divisible by 2 and 3 is 6

Comment: ahh... That makes sense.

Comment: ok see your set  $\pi=\{\ 2, 3 \}\ $. Now what is a $\pi$ number. It is nothing but just a number for which if we do the prime decomposition you will get only the members of the set $\pi$. For example consider 24=$2^{3}.3$, hence 24 is a $\pi$-number. Now the question is what is $n_{\pi}$ right? consider a number $n$. Do its prime decomposition. Now you will be easiily able to see what is the largest $\pi$ number that divides $n$. In your case 30=2.3.5 . Clearly it is 6, that is, 2.3